# Mysql order by two colums independetly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table in mysql:

Table 1

```
ID       DiscountPrice    ActualPrice
1        2299.00             2874.00
2        0                   50
3        2999.00             3499.00
4        0.00                4999.00
5        3899.00             5999.00
```

I want this should come in sorted order(lowest should come first)

Output:

```
ID: 2 , 1, 3, 5, 4
```

Please help me.

Comment: lowest in DiscountPrice or ActualPrice ?

Comment: Lowest of what value? A simple `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 ORDER BY DiscountPrice` should work for you

Comment: In which basis are you trying to sort it? `ctualPrice` or `DiscountPrice` or `ActualPrice`-`DiscountPrice`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
ORDER BY 
  LEAST(
    IF(DiscountPrice=0, 1E18, DiscountPrice), 
    IF(ActualPrice=0, 1E18, ActualPrice)
  )
```

-I'm doing `IF` since you need to deal only with non-zero values.

Answer (score 2):

Lowest of what value?

A simple

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 ORDER BY DiscountPrice
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 ORDER BY ActualPrice
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 ORDER BY DiscountPrice, ActualPrice ASC
```

should work for you

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY DiscountPrice`

You can also do
`SELECT * FROM tabl1 ORDER BY DiscountPrice, ActualPrice`
This way in case the DiscountPrice is equal to for both of them it will look at the ActualPrice.

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your question.

```
SELECT `id`, `ActualPrice` FROM "your_table_name" ORDER BY `ActualPrice` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1 ORDER BY DiscountPrice, ActualPrice ASC)

while(row = mysql_fetch_array(result))     
{
   a=row['DiscountPrice'];
   b=row['ActualPrice'];
   echo min(a);
   echo min(b);
}
```